# If more than 10% of results are over X in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a database table with lists of temperature readings from many locations in a number of buildings. I need a query that will give me a true or false if more than 10% of the readings in a building, taken on a date, are greater than X

I am not looking for a average. If there are 100 measurements taken in a building on a date, and 10 of them are over X (say 80 degrees) then create a flag.

The table is laid out as

```
 Building # location #    date     temperature
| 123      |  555      |2016-04-08 | 68.5     |
| 123      |  556      |2016-04-08 | 70.2     |
| 123      |  557      |2016-04-08 | 65.4     |
| 888      |  999      |2013-03 22 | 80.4     |
```

Typically a building would have over 100 readings. There are many hundreds of building/date entries in the table

Can this be done with a single mysql query and can you share that query with me?

---

I obviously haven't made my question clear.

The result I am looking for is a single True or False.

If more than 10% of the results for a building/date combination were over X (say 80%) then show true, or some flag equal to true.

The known fields will be building and date. The location is not relevant, and can be ignored. So given the input of building (123) and date (2016-04-08) are more than 10% of the entries in the table that have that building number and date greater than X (e.g. 80). The only data to be tested are those for that building and date. So the query would end in:

```
where building_id=`123` AND date =`2016-04-08`
```

I am NOT looking for an average or a median. I am NOT looking to see a list of the data for that 10%. I am just looking for true or false.

Comment: No idea unless you post table structure / sample data / desired output

Comment: yes, this can be done with single mysql query

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation, something like this:

```
select building, date,
       (case when avg(temperature > x) > 0.1 then 'Y' else 'N' end) as flag
from t
group by building, date;
```

Comment: Can I ask why you use a `case` statement when there is only one argument? Why not just use a `if(avg(temperature) > x,'Y','N')`. Also your `avg()` function looks weird here. Is the `)` supposed to be between `temperature` and `>`? Sorry but you have heaps of reputation so I figure you're used to helping people understand different syntaxes etc

Comment: @tomb . . . `if()` is not standard SQL.  Why introduce a new function, when that functionality already exists?

Comment: so is it a way of keeping coding similar across different languages? That'd make sense because I only know MySQL and BigQuery which both have `if()` and even then I've only been using them for a couple of years. Cheers

Comment: @tomb . . . `case` is the ANSI standard way of expression a conditional expression.  It is more flexible than `if()`, and I don't find the savings of a few extra key strokes to be worth using a non-standard function.

Comment: I think I must have been unclear, so I updated the question.

Comment: @coderking . . . And why doesn't this answer your question?  Just add a `where` clause for the building and date that you want.

Answer (score 0):

To return building and date, and "create a flag" for rows where more than 10% of the readings for that building on that date are over a given value X ...

```
 SELECT r.building
      , DATE(r.date)
      , ( SUM(r.reading > X ) > SUM(.10) ) AS _flag
   FROM myreadings r
  GROUP BY r.building, DATE(r.date)
```

Absent more specification about the actual resultset you want to return, we're just guessing at what result set you want to return.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Based on the update to the question...  to return a row for a single building and a single date, add the WHERE clause as shown in the question. And remove expressions from the SELECT list.

```
 SELECT ( SUM(r.reading > X ) > SUM(.10) ) AS _flag
   FROM myreadings r
  WHERE r.building = '123'
    AND r.date    >= '2016-04-08'
    AND r.date    <  '2016-04-08' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

If there are no rows for the given building and given date, the query will return zero rows. If there is at least one row, and the number of rows that have a reading greater than X is more than 10% of the total number of rows, the query will return a single row, with _flag having a value of 1 (TRUE). Otherwise, the query will return a single row with _flag having a value of 0 (FALSE).

If you want the query to return a row even when there are no matching rows in the table, that can be accomplished with a more complex SQL statement.

If you want the query to return string values `'TRUE'` or `'FALSE'`, that can be accomplished as well.

Again, absent an *example* of the resultset you are expecting to have returned, (without an actual specification which we can compare a resultset to), we're just guessing.